# In Python 3, how to copy a key-value mapping from one dict to another, including remove if necessary?

Tags: python

In Python 3, how to copy a key-value mapping from one dict to another, including remove if necessary? Here's some ugly code to do this:

```
if key in dict2:
  dict1[key] = dict2[key]
elif key in dict1:
  del dict1[key]
```

I'm hoping someone can reply with a cleaner and hopefully one-liner way to do this. (And I don't mean "just put that ugly code inside a function" because I don't want to add a hundred little functions to my code.) TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Since one comment asked for context, and others have tried to give answers that don't actually do what the question stated, I'm going to give an example context -- this isn't exactly what I'm trying to do, but it'll give you a good idea. I just wrote up this code quickly without testing, so hopefully it's not so wrong that I don't get the idea across. Note the ugly code I asked about originally is toward the bottom of this expanded example. TIA.

```
class TimestampedDict(dict):

  def __init__(self):
    self._ts = {}  # from key to timestamp

  def __setitem__(self, key, val):
    super().__setitem__(key, val)
    self._ts[key] = datetime.now()

  def __delitem__(self, key):
    super().__delitem__(key)
    # When deleting, timestamp is updated by 1 microsecond so that it wins
    # against the original but loses to any later changes.
    self._ts[key] = self._ts[key] + timedelta(microseconds=1)

  def update(self, other):
    for key in other._ts:
      if key not in self._ts or self._ts[key] < other._ts[key]:
        # Other wins, so replace the mapping (including del if necessary).
        if key in other:
          self[key] = other[key]
        elif key in self:
          del self[key]
        self._ts[key] = other._ts[key]
```

Comment: Where are the keys coming from? With an out-of-context snippet, how can we make sensible suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with just making a copy of dict2: `dict1 = dict2.copy()`? Or if you can't replace the container, `dict1.clear(); dict1.update(dict2)`

Comment: I don't think you can improve your logic because the first condition selects only a subset of keys, and you can only `del` a single item or `clear` all items from a dict. What do you do if the `_ts[key]`s are equal?

Comment: @achampion If `_ts[key]`s are equal down to the microsecond, then in my usage it's safe to assume the values are same without checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned I don't think there is much to improve with your logic but I find it interesting to see how twisted one can get, so here's a really ugly way of doing it using `update()`:

```
def update(other):
    u = {k: v for k, v in other._ts.items() if k not in self._ts or self._ts[k] < v}
    self._ts.update(u)
    dict.update({k: other[k] for k in u 
                 if k in other or (self.pop(k, 0) and False})
```

You are guaranteed `(self.pop(k, 0) and False)` evaluates to `False` but also has the side effect of removing `k` from self. This will only be evaluated if `k in other` evaluates to `False`.

```
>>> a = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
>>> b = {1:2, 2:3}
>>> a.update({k: b[k] for k in [1,2,3] if k in b or (a.pop(k, 0) and False)})
>>> a
{1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 4}
```

Comment: Congrats. I think your code basically works, except you meant to type `k not in self._ts` in the first statement. Also, it'd be simpler to do `(k in self and self.pop(k) and False)` to guarantee a False result rather than comparing the value against itself. This code is too unreadable to use, though. In the end, maybe the simplest one-liner in response to my original question is simply `dict1.__setitem__(key, dict2[key]) if key in dict2 else dict1.__delitem__(key)`, but that's also too unreadable to use. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding, but you are looking to create update dict1 with the values from dict2 and remove those that are missing?  In that case  couldn't you simply set dict1 = dict2?

Otherwise if you are looking to combine two dictionaries and update shared keys, maybe the following will work:

```
dict1 = {1:2,3:4,5:6}
dict2 = {1:7}
dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())
```

The addition of the items of the 2 dictionaries, will produce a new dictionary with all keys, and the values of the second dictionary if overlapping.  However after rereading your question I believe you are looking for the former solution (dict1 = dict2).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `update`:

If this isn't what you want, can you please provide sample data and desired result?

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
d1.update(d2)

>>> d1
{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```